# Guice: bind parameters that do NOT have an annotation

Tags: guice

I have a situation where I need to bind interface I to class A in about 40 instances, but bind it to class B in only 2 other instances. I can of course name it, or annotate it in all 42 cases, but it would  be more clean if I would be able annotate only the 2 exceptions. Is it possible to particularly target all the instances that do NOT have an annotation?

Comment: As a point of interest, in hk2 you can specifically @Inject something that is NOT qualified with a particular annotation.  See https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b06/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Unqualified.html.  We have found such a thing useful from time to time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to target those injection points requiring the A implementation - you just need to write a binding for them. Recall that every binding in Guice is represented with a `Key` and make sure to add one for both cases. This way any `I` without a binding annotation gets `A` and any `I` properly annotated gets `B`.

```java
static interface I {}
static class A implements I {}
static class B implements I {}

static class C {
  @Inject I a;
  @Inject @Named("b") I b;
}

static class Module extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(I.class).to(A.class);
    bind(I.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("b")).to(B.class);
  }
}

@Test
public void test() {
  Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new Module());
  C c = i.getInstance(C.class);
  assertThat(c.a, is(instanceOf(A.class)));
  assertThat(c.b, is(instanceOf(B.class)));
}
```